# Xcode bots server continuous integration hangs on "Getting sources..."

Tags: ios, continuous-integration, xcode5, osx-server

I setup a copy of OSX server and correctly configured it with Xcode. I was able to create a bot and run a few integrations which failed because I didn't import the correct developer certificates. Running an integration now it seems to be stuck at "Getting sources.." while Xcode is showing it as being queued. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are lot of reasons this might be happening and it depends on what version control system you are using. For both git and svn the issue might be the root ssl certificates. You need to add the root certificates from your keychain to your ssl configuration.

See [this post](http://jw35.blogspot.gr/2011/02/root-certificates-for-macos-openssl.html) for details.

If the problem isn't SSL certificate related then it will likely be a timeout issue fetching your source repository if it is very large. Check your integration logs for details.